# How to display image like that images/series/20200518140210_HgQ2G.jpg from json in flutter?

Tags: json, image, flutter

This object image display like that from json cCover1": "images/series/20200518140210_HgQ2G.jpg" so how to add base url to object cCover1 to  display image

Comment: this object appear in json like that    "cCover1": "images/series/20200518140210_HgQ2G.jpg",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try decoding the `JSON` to `Map` and then concatenate your baseUrl with cCover1

For example,

```
String baseUrl = "baseUrl";
String json = '{"cCover1":"someUrl"}';//Your Json String
Map<String,dynamic> map = jsonDecode(json);
String imageUrl = baseUrl + map["cCover1"];
```

Hope this helps!